# Diffrence between is gone and has gone

Tags: sentence-construction

Which sentence is correct and why?

Me and I were waiting on bus stand. I reached before my friend to the stop. He came to stop after 10 min and asked me about bus status. 
How Should I Say

> "The bus **is not yet gone** from our stop." current status (Indicates State of Being not gone)

or

> "The bus **has not yet gone** from our stop." Action buy bus (Indicates relative time of Being not gone)

One more example
He is gone out of the house.
Or
He has gone out of the house

Comment: Is the bus standing at the stop, waiting? Or has it not even arrived yet? In the latter case, you'd say "the bus has not yet **come**".

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence is "the has not yet gone from our stop.

Is gone means "is no longer here".
has gone means "went somewhere. The destination is specified or understood.

It doesn't sound natural if we say he is gone out of the house or he is gone to school when there is a specified place of departure or destination. Usually, we say he has gone out of the house.  However, it is common to say that he is gone or the bus is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences can be correct as answers to simple questions.  Though I use bus stop more as a bus station.  Or, remove the "from our stop" ending phrase.  Leading to the simple:

The bus is gone.
The bus has gone.

The bus is not yet gone.
The bus has not yet gone.

Late Friend:  "Where is the bus?  Is the bus gone?"
You : "Don't worry.  The bus is not yet gone from our stop.  It is being refueled around the corner."

Late Friend:  "I don't see the bus.  Has the bus gone already?"
You : "Don't worry.  The bus has not yet gone from our stop.  It has to complete a checkup."

Answer (score -1):

In both your examples "is gone" version is not correct.

You could simply say that: "The bus is still at the stop" or "The bus is still at our stop"

And for the last example, the correct version would be: "He left the house" or "He has just left the house". Because "He has gone out of the house" although grammatical, seems to mean that he probably doesn't return soon enough.

Comment: I think "the bus has not yet **come**" may even be closer to the intended meaning.

Comment: @oerkelens Yeah, with 'come' yes.

Comment: I mean that what the OP is asking is likely not a situation where the bus is still waiting at the stop (the question would be strange - unless the asker is blind!). So what the OP means with "current situation" is probably "the bus is not at the stop. It has not left yet, because it has not arrived yet". This makes for a common situation, and a common question at bus stops.

Comment: @oerkelens In that case "the bus has not yet come" sounds very good.